# Using a function to change object orientated tkinter code

Tags: python, tkinter

I seem to be unable to change the button text in the GUI with a function when using the object orientated way of writing the code.

I am able to print it in the console when I click the button but I am unable to change the GUI.

Again I can make this work in a none object orientated way.

I would really appreciate any help I have been stuck on this for way to long lol

Thanks

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk


# tk class open
class main(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args)

        main.minsize(self, width=250, height=300)

        frame = tk.Frame(self, bg='red')
        frame.pack(side='left', fill='both', expand=True)

        self.button = Button(frame, text='heloo', command=self.change)
        self.button.pack()

    def change(self):
        self.button.configure(self, text='now1')
        self.button.pack()
        print('This works but does not change the button in the GUI')

app = main()
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove `self` from the call to `configure`:

```
self.button.configure(text='now1`)
```

Also, you don't need to call `self.button.pack()` in `change`. In this example it's harmless, but if you had other widgets then it might do something you don't expect.